# default value in mysql table id

Tags: mysql, database, invoice

I have the id which is the primary. It has auto increment.

When ever I try to enter a default value like for example: 000   - it does not start counting from that number but from 0,1,2,3 etc...

how can i make it 000?

Or in my case I really want it for a invoice - say 2011-000 and start counting can it be possible??

any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

For making your column to contain 000, you will need to make it `zerofill`. So, Alter your table with `zerofill` option for your column.

You can read more about zerofill ,

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Also, as ajreal suggested, you will need to physically update column to zero.

Comment: @ajreal: Thanks, can you tell me about my mistake above so that i can take care of it in future. This will be new learning for me.

Comment: I don't think able to set auto_increment to zero (unless you physically update it to zero)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to bother between 0000 and 0001 ?

**PS** - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero

> NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO affects handling of AUTO_INCREMENT columns. Normally, you generate the next sequence number for the column by inserting either NULL or 0 into it. NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO suppresses this behavior for 0 so that only NULL generates the next sequence number.
>
> This mode can be useful if 0 has been stored in a table's AUTO_INCREMENT column. (Storing 0 is not a recommended practice, by the way.) For example, if you dump the table with mysqldump and then reload it, MySQL normally generates new sequence numbers when it encounters the 0 values, resulting in a table with contents different from the one that was dumped. Enabling NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO before reloading the dump file solves this problem. mysqldump now automatically includes in its output a statement that enables NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO, to avoid this problem.

Hope the following make sense without change `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` ...

```
mysql> create table invoice (years int(4) unsigned, 
seq int(4) unsigned zerofill not null auto_increment, 
primary key(years, seq));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into invoice values (2011, 0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update invoice set seq=0;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table invoice auto_increment=0;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into invoice values (2011, 0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from invoice;
+-------+------+
| years | seq  |
+-------+------+
|  2011 | 0000 |
|  2011 | 0001 |
+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into invoice values (2011, 0), (2011, 0);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from invoice;
+-------+------+
| years | seq  |
+-------+------+
|  2011 | 0000 |
|  2011 | 0001 |
|  2011 | 0002 |
|  2011 | 0003 |
+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```